# Spring Cloud Security: How to support multiple Identity Provider for Oauth2 Resource Server / OAuth2 Authorization Server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-cloud

I want to build a spring cloud infrastructure with several oauth2 resource servers supporting multiple identity provider (like google, facebook, github, ....) and also one self implemented authorization mechanism.

**Oauth2 Resource Server example**

*Security config*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class Oauth2ResourceServerConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

*application.yml*

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: https://api.github.com/user
```

As you can see this example is using github as identity provider and its working fine.

**Oauth2 Authorization Server example:**

*Config*

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}user").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
    }
}
```

*application.yml*

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: user
      client-secret: user
      authorized-grant-types: password,client_credentials,authorization_code,refresh_token
      scope: read,write
```

I can change my oauth2 resource server to use the authorization server:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      #user-info-uri: https://api.github.com/user
      user-info-uri: http://${AUTH_HOST:localhost}:${AUTH_PORT:9000}/user
```

And it works just fine.

But what do I have to do if I now want to use both of them, github and my own authorization server?
Do I simply need a different configuration in my Oauth2 resource server to provide multiple `user-info-uri` or do I have to do more?

Can I extend my own authorization service to support github & co?

I would prefer not to use Auth0 and Co because I really dont like to outsource the most important part of my application: security. Even though I would like to try it. But I could not find any working example so far for auth0 + spring cloud gateway + token authentication for all underlying services.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I'm currently trying to implement the same. I can find some resources using SAML but not with oauth2

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same. Did you guys found a solution for that?

Comment: Hi, no, not yet.

Comment: I know it's been 3 years, but have you managed to resolve it? Do you have any examples or reference material? Thanks in advance!